# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: python, sql, django

I recently started a django project and I am having trouble accessing a sqlite3 database that I recently added. I ran `python manage.py inspectdb --database 'football'` after inserting the new database into settings.py. This gave me the file that I copy pasted into models.py. From there I ran `makemigrations` which gave me this error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
teambuilder.Countries.country_id: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.
        HINT: Set null=False on the field, or remove primary_key=True argument.
teambuilder.Playertransferhistory: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.
teambuilder.Teams.team_id: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.
        HINT: Set null=False on the field, or remove primary_key=True argument.
(venv) Jacks-MBP:SportWebsite Tilley$ python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
teambuilder.Playertransferhistory.id: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.
        HINT: Set null=False on the field, or remove primary_key=True argument.
```

From there I changed null to false where needed and reran `makemigrations`
which gave me this:

```
Migrations for 'teambuilder':
  teambuilder/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Countries
    - Create model LeagueGames
    - Create model Leagues
    - Create model Playerinfo
    - Create model Playertransferhistory
    - Create model Teams
```

followed by `migrate` which outputted:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites, teambuilder
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I then ran `python manage.py shell` and typed in the following commands:

```
from teambuilder.models import *
Leagues.objects.all()
```

which presented me with this red wall:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Leagues

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 244, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Tilley/PycharmProjects/SportWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Leagues
```

I know that the table does exist but I cannot understand why I'm getting this error. I've seen similar questions here on SO but none of the solutions have fixed my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you deleted your migrations and again done makemigrations?

Comment: I have tried this. However I was told after that deleting migrations is not a good idea.

Comment: Which os you are using?